# Excel VBA Range variable concatenation

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, ms-word

I Have the below Chunk of Excel VBA Code .
Now I'll have to put them In a Loop & Parametrize them.

```
Countruz2 = 2
 Countruz3 = Countruz2 + 13

Range("A2:A15").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Below is what I've tried - 3 variants all failing with:  Invalid use of Property Error.

```
'    Range ("A" & Countruz2 & ":" & "A" & Countruz3)                                    ' Invalid Use of Property

'    Range ("A" & Countruz2 & ":A" & Countruz3)                                         ' Invalid Use of Property

'    Range ("A" & Countruz2 & ":A" & Countruz2 + 13)                                    ' Invalid Use of Property
```

How do we deal with Such Concatenations & Parametrizations within the Range function in Excel VBA ?

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Edit :

Got it working after concatenating it like this -

X = "A" & Countruz2 & ":" & "A" & (Countruz2 + 13)
Debug.Print X
Range(X).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

Any other elegant / simpler way?

Comment: You only need the top-left cell for the destination of a paste. Anything else is overkill and just another possible error when you get the destination size or orientation wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Countruz2 = 2
Countruz3 = Countruz2 + 13

Range("A" & Countruz2 & ":A" & Countruz3).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```